# Why the algorithm gives different answers for C++ and Python?

Tags: python, c++, algorithm

I do an algorithm exercise today. This question's tutorial gives an example answer written in C++:

```
int dp[21][200];
int i, j, k;
 
void main()
{
    int bucketN, fishN;
    scanf("%d %d", &bucketN, &fishN);
 
    dp[0][0] = 1;  
 
    for(int i = 1; i <= bucketN; ++i) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= fishN; ++j)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k <= 10 && j-k >= 0; ++k)
            {
                dp[i][j] += dp[i-1][j-k];
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",dp[bucketN][fishN]);
}
```

If the `bucketN` and `fishN` are both 20, the output would be `65649764`.

I translated the C++ implementation into Python and my code is shown as follows.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.zeros((21, 200))

def main(bucket, fish):

    b, f = bucket, fish
    arr[0, 0] = 1

    for i in range(1, b+1):
        for j in range(f+1):
            for k in range(11):
                if j-k < 0:
                    break
                else:
                    arr[i, j] += arr[i-1, j-k]
    
    print(arr[b, f])
    return arr[b, f]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(20, 20)
```

Both of the `bucket` and `fish` is still 20, but the output is `68785126410.0`.

I feel very confused and I think that my code is the same as the original C++ one. Hope that someone expert on C++ or Python can explain it.

Comment: Can you print out the whole arrays to see where the numbers start becoming inconsistent, or if there's an obvious pattern in the discrepancies?

Comment: The Python code gives the accurate answer but the C code overflows the datatype.

Comment: Change your array declaration in your C code to `long long` instead of `int`, then `%lld` instead of `%d` to print the right value. Also, not sure why you think that's C++.

Comment: @ggorlen "_The Python code gives the accurate answer_" - It gives an answer. "accurate" doesn't come into play.

Comment: @TedLyngmo What do you mean?

Comment: @ggorlen Sorry for being vague: What is _the_ accurate answer? Is it different for different floating points or is there a general agreement?

Comment: @Calculuswhiz That works. Thanks.

Comment: It's not entirely clear why they're not using integers, but the Python output gives an accurate answer relative to C if the C code uses a datatype that doesn't overflow. That's enough for resolving OP's issue here although it'd be nice if they provided problem context. I guess that isn't relevant. BTW, good idea to `return 0` and `int main` and the code can overflow the array and probably some other issues but ignoring that stuff too. I voted to close as off topic/no longer reproducible.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz - The code is not actually valid C either - not sure why you think it is.   It takes more than usage of `printf()` and `scanf()` and usage of raw arrays to justify deeming code as being C rather than C++.

Comment: @Peter I was looking at the `void main` primarily. GCC for C and clang for C both allow `void main` or even just `main` by default. The same compilers for C++ will not allow a `void main`. Of course, that's assuming we have an `stdio`. But, yes, according to any modern spec, it's not valid C either. Oops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the C++ code, the data type for `dp` array is int, which can hold upto the number 2147483647. The true non-overflown answer you are looking for is returned by your python code 68785126410. Change the first line in your C++ code from:
`int dp[21][200];`
to
`long long int dp[21][200];`
and the printf format specifier from `"%d` to `%lld` to see matching (and correct) answers in C++ and Python

Comment: Interesting fun fact: It's actually worse and weirder than you describe. `int` might only be able to hold a maximum of 32767. And may it holds gajillions. Only the minimum size of an `int` is specified, and that's 16 bits. The implementors can make it anything the want larger than that so long as it's not bigger than a `long`. It can even be the same size as a `long`. I've seen systems where all of the integer types were the same size.

Comment: Don't forget the `int main`, `return 0;`, and the `#include <cstdio>`! This is C++ we're talking about. (Though I'm not sure why `cstdio` was chosen over `iostream`.)

Comment: `int64_t` is a better choice in general than `long long` because it's a known size, and so you can more easily figure out if it's large enough for your calculations. Although in practice, `long long` is 64 bits on all modern compilers. If you don't need negative numbers (which it looks like is the case for your problem), `uint64_t` gives you an extra bit.

Comment: Running your C/C++ code with ubsan can also greatly help to find problems, including signed integer overflows.